# .Net core 5.0 console app referencing a model building in .Net framework4.7.2

Tags: .net-core, model, entity-framework-6, console-application

I have a entity framework Data access layer building in .Net framework 4.7.2

And I am trying to reference it from .Net core console app.

I keep getting the error
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

I have added the below code based on the suggestions on web, but then the error change to a different method which uses system.configuration and the error goes 'cannot initialize the configuration' system.data is invalid config section

```
     <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <!--<add name="dotConnect for PostgreSQL" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL" type="Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlProviderFactory, Devart.Data.PostgreSql, Version= 7.17.1583.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />-->

      <!--<add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />-->
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />

    <remove invariant="Npgsql" /><add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core you need to call [DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.registerfactory?view=net-5.0) instead of using config files.

```
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("NpgSql", Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
```

Comment: I am not using the model in core project. Core project has reference to model written using .net framework 4.7  and that config has 
    <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, 
    error occured in efdal model whenlinq query runs   
    'var ls = context.ld203
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               x.ld203_id,
                               x.fedlob_qtr_id,
                })'

Comment: the config data are read by the executing program, not the lib